Mend is reporting malicious code vulnerability - fsevents -v 1.2.4 angular
getting malicious code vulnerability from mend and the solution is to upgrade the fsevents version from 1.2.4 to 1.2.11. Current angular-cli version of the project is 6.0.8, angular/core version is 6.0.0.
Can anyone tells me how can I upgrade fsevents package from 1.2.4 to 1.2.11 without causing any issue to other dependencies.
I tried using npm i fsevents@1.2.11. It updated the version but started giving errors on other dependencies.
